# How can i get my transition working because nothing works?

Tags: css, transition

I tried multiple things like changing the transition duration by a transition all with the duration and others but it never worked. Send help

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/LeLicorne/pen/ZEqpwPJ

```css
:root {
  --homeBookmark-after-left: 0px;
  --homeBookmark-after-top: 0px;
  --homeBookmark-Color: #9747FF;
  --skillsBookmark-Color: #0079D0;
  --workBookmark-Color: #00EA25;
  --contactBookmark-Color: #F05600;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
  position: fixed;
}

header nav {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
}

header nav a {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}

header nav a:hover {
  height: 70px;
}


/* #homeBookmark::after{  it s the 'a'
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: var(--homeBookmark-after-left);
    top: var(--homeBookmark-after-top);
    background: transparent;
    border-right: 23px solid transparent;
    border-left: 23px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid purple;
} */

#homeBookmark {
  background-color: var(--homeBookmark-Color);
}

#skillsBookmark {
  background-color: var(--skillsBookmark-Color);
}

#workBookmark {
  background-color: var(--workBookmark-Color);
}

#contactBookmark {
  background-color: var(--contactBookmark-Color);
}

header nav a i {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="homeBookmark"><i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="skillsBookmark"><!-- <i class="bi bi-wrench-adjustable-circle-fill"></i> --><i class="bi bi-pie-chart-fill"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="workBookmark"><i class="bi bi-folder-fill"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="contactBookmark"><i class="bi bi-person-lines-fill"></i></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

tried changing transition-duration to transition all 250ms and the other things of needed
and also i tried with the -webkit- -moz- and -ms- transition and didn't work

Comment: Welcome! _doesn't work_ doesn't mean anything to us. What are you expecting to happen? If you mean the `a` tags growing, It's because you don't set the `transition` property anywhere. Remove your `transition-duration` property and replace it with `transition: all .25s ease;` You also need to add a `height` property to the `header nav a` rule - that's the main reason you aren't seeing the transition happening.

Comment: @InSync I hope so! I haven't looked at the spec recently, but I would think that CSS4/Browser support might be able to determine an `auto` value and convert it to a unit to allow transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you need to add:

1. `transition: all .25s ease` - since you need the `transition` property. You could also target just the `height` value, since that's what you're changing: `transition: height 250ms ease`
2. You need to add a `height` property to the main `header nav a`. You'll have to determine the correct value. I used `10px` as a placeholder.

```css
:root {
  --homeBookmark-after-left: 0px;
  --homeBookmark-after-top: 0px;
  --homeBookmark-Color: #9747FF;
  --skillsBookmark-Color: #0079D0;
  --workBookmark-Color: #00EA25;
  --contactBookmark-Color: #F05600;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #222222;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: start;
  position: fixed;
}

header nav {
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 50px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
}

header nav a {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
  height: 10px;
}

header nav a:hover {
  height: 70px;
}


/* #homeBookmark::after{  it s the 'a'
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    left: var(--homeBookmark-after-left);
    top: var(--homeBookmark-after-top);
    background: transparent;
    border-right: 23px solid transparent;
    border-left: 23px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid purple;
} */

#homeBookmark {
  background-color: var(--homeBookmark-Color);
}

#skillsBookmark {
  background-color: var(--skillsBookmark-Color);
}

#workBookmark {
  background-color: var(--workBookmark-Color);
}

#contactBookmark {
  background-color: var(--contactBookmark-Color);
}

header nav a i {
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#" id="homeBookmark"><i class="bi bi-house-fill"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="skillsBookmark"><i class="bi bi-pie-chart-fill"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="workBookmark"><i class="bi bi-folder-fill"></i></a>
    <a href="#" id="contactBookmark"><i class="bi bi-person-lines-fill"></i></a>
  </nav>
</header>
```